# If condition in Shiny server

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, reactive

I'm trying to manipulate a dataframe based on the input. Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("chart", click = "SD1"),
  radioButtons(
    "term",
    "Term",
    choices = c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"),
  ))

server <- function(input, output){
  df1 <- reactive(getSymbols("JPM", src = "google", auto.assign = F))
  output$chart <- renderPlot(
    if (input$term == "Weekly") {
      df <- to.weekly(df1())
    }
    else if (input$term == "Monthly") {
      df <- to.monthly(df1())
    }
    else {
      df <- df1()
    }
    chartSeries(
      df()
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So why my if condition doesn't work? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got your brackets mixed up, this should do the job. If you want to use your subset data and still keep access to original you can create two reactives: one you can access with `df1()` and the other is `df()`

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("chart", click = "SD1"),
  radioButtons(
    "term",
    "Term",
    choices = c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"),
  ))

server <- function(input, output){
  df1 <- reactive({getSymbols("JPM", src = "google", auto.assign = F)})

  df <-reactive({
    if (input$term == "Weekly") {
      df <- to.weekly(df1())
    }
    else if (input$term == "Monthly") {
      df <- to.monthly(df1())
    }
    else {
      df <- df1()
    }
    return(df)
  })

  output$chart <- renderPlot({

    chartSeries(df())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you it works. So what is the purpose of `print(input$term)`? BTW, how can I call `df` outside `renderPlot`?

Comment: I added example how to access df outside the plot, the `print(input$term)` to see if I needed to take care of a null or not, u dont really need that there